# HTML and PHP, Creating an HTML Email with two columns

Tags: html, css, php

Okay, so my issue is I want two columns. I want information about the current schools headmaster and some other people's titles and their names on the left with the actual letter on the right. However, all the people's titles and there names are displaying above the letter instead of the left. I was wondering if someone can look over my code and tell me what I missed. I think it is probably a dumb syntax error or I forgot to declare a line but I just can't see it.

Thanks

```
    These are the headers:
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

And this is the message:

$message = "

<HTML>
<HEAD>

<STYLE type=\"text/css\">
body {margin-top: 0px;margin-left: 0px;}
#page_1 {position:relative; overflow: hidden;margin: 169px 0px 121px 34px;padding: 0px;border: none;width: 782px;}
#page_1 #id_1 {float:left;border:none;margin: 98px 0px 0px 0px;padding: 0px;border:none;width: 182px;overflow: hidden;}
#page_1 #id_2 {float:left;border:none;margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;padding: 0px;border:none;width: 600px;overflow: hidden;}
.ft0{font: bold 13px 'Times New Roman';text-decoration: underline;color: #47744c;line-height: 15px;}
.ft1{font: bold 12px 'Times New Roman';text-decoration: underline;color: #47744c;line-height: 14px;}
.ft2{font: bold 12px 'Times New Roman';color: #47744c;line-height: 15px;}
.ft3{font: bold 12px 'Times New Roman';text-decoration: underline;color: #47744c;line-height: 13px;}
.ft4{font: italic bold 12px 'Times New Roman';color: #47744c;line-height: 14px;}
.ft5{font: italic bold 12px 'Times New Roman';color: #47744c;line-height: 15px;}
.ft6{font: 16px 'Times New Roman';line-height: 19px;}
.ft7{font: italic 12px 'Times New Roman';line-height: 15px;}
.ft8{font: 15px 'Arial';line-height: 17px;}

.p0{text-align: left;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p1{text-align: left;margin-top: 13px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p2{text-align: left;margin-top: 1px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p3{text-align: left;margin-top: 12px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p4{text-align: left;margin-top: 11px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p5{text-align: left;margin-top: 2px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p6{text-align: left;margin-top: 25px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p7{text-align: left;padding-right: 384px;margin-top: 73px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p8{text-align: left;margin-top: 16px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p9{text-align: left;padding-right: 123px;margin-top: 18px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p10{text-align: left;padding-right: 123px;margin-top: 33px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p11{text-align: left;margin-top: 53px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p12{text-align: left;margin-top: 54px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p13{text-align: left;padding-right: 131px;margin-top: 17px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
.p14{text-align: left;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;white-space: nowrap;}
.p15{text-align: left;padding-left: 29px;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;white-space: nowrap;}

.td0{padding: 0px;margin: 0px;width: 115px;vertical-align: bottom;}
.td1{padding: 0px;margin: 0px;width: 103px;vertical-align: bottom;}

.tr0{height: 17px;}
.tr1{height: 22px;}

.t0{width: 218px;margin-left: 96px;margin-top: 17px;font: 15px 'Arial';}

</STYLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<DIV id=\"page_1\">


<DIV>
<DIV id=\"id_1\">
<P class=\"p0 ft0\">Board of Trustees</P>
<P class=\"p1 ft1\">REDACTED</P>
<P class=\"p6 ft4\">“Nurturing Hearts,</P>
<P class=\"p2 ft5\">Developing Minds”</P>
</DIV>
<DIV id=\"id_2\">
<P class=\"p0 ft6\">$today</P>
<P class=\"p7 ft6\">$title $first_name  $last_name<br>$street_address<br>$city, $state $zip</P>
<P class=\"p8 ft6\">Dear $title $last_name,</P>
<P class=\"p9 ft6\">We have received your generous donation of $$mathAmt.00, and we are truly grateful. Since its founding in 1970, The School has been fortunate to receive philanthropic support from forward looking people like you who understand and appreciate the unique significance of our school’s mission in our community. Over these past <NOBR>forty-one</NOBR> years, many of our graduates have become respected professionals and leaders in our community, and our school is widely acknowledged as an important education resource in our region.</P>
<P class=\"p10 ft6\">On behalf of the Board of Trustees, the Faculty, and our Students, who are the ultimate recipients of your generosity, I wish to personally thank you. Your sacrificial donation sends an especially powerful message during theses challenging economic times about your devotion to the school.</P>
<P class=\"p11 ft6\">Sincerely yours,</P>
<P class=\"p12 ft6\">James </P>
<P class=\"p0 ft6\">Headmaster</P>
<P class=\"p13 ft8\">For tax purposes, School is pleased to provide the following information. No goods or services were rendered in exchange for this contribution. Please retain this letter for income tax purposes. This written acknowledgement of your donation serves as the substantiation required under section 170 of the Internal Revenue Code.</P>
<TABLE cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class=\"t0\">
<TR>
    <TD class=\"tr0 td0\"><P class=\"p14 ft8\">Date of Gift:</P></TD>
    <TD class=\"tr0 td1\"><P class=\"p15 ft8\">1/19/2012</P></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD class=\"tr1 td0\"><P class=\"p14 ft8\">Value of Gift*<SPAN class=\"ft6\">:</SPAN></P></TD>
    <TD class=\"tr1 td1\"><P class=\"p15 ft8\">$$mathAmt.00</P></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>

</body>
</HTML>

";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your email looks fine if you load it in a browser, so I don't think you are doing anything wrong, EXCEPT this:

Most email clients don't support div based layouts or non-inline styles. You need to redo your email with tables for layout and all of your css inline (or declared via deprecated html attributes).

http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/ might help you with some of the email idiosyncrasies.

Comment: Stack Overflow won't let me edit the post to only add a JSFiddle link, but you can see the working email at http://jsfiddle.net/Tpf3B/

Comment: Yea, I noticed it looked fine in a browser but I am pretty new to this so I figured I still was screwing something up, haha. Thanks for the suggestion I will try it.

Comment: Take your time with it. Writing HTML emails can be quite difficult compared to making a "regular" website. Just make sure your stuff validates on the big stuff (using attributes that aren't "supported" isn't a big deal, but making sure your tr's and table's are all closed is). Also, check http://premailer.dialect.ca/ to move the css you do write from a style block into inline styles.